# Django cannot run with http

Tags: django, python-3.x, http, http-status-code-404

After open server, web only run without "http" url
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4azv.jpg)127.0.0.1:8000/blog/
and add http with 404 ERROR,where I did wrong?

Comment: include your urls.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now you are developing the Django not deploying it on the server. The http or https will be set with the server configuration file. It don't work now. Simply develop your site and figure this out when you are deploying the app